# Get items from xml Python

Tags: python, xml, elementtree, findall

I have an xml in python, need to obtain the elements of the "Items" tag in an iterable list.

**I need get a iterable list from this XML, for example like it:**

- Item 1: Bicycle, value $250, iva_tax: 50.30
- Item 2: Skateboard, value $120, iva_tax: 25.0

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<data>
    <info>Listado de items</info>
    <detalle>
        <![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <tienda id="tiendaProd" version="1.1.0">
            <items>
                <item>
                    <nombre>Bicycle</nombre>
                    <valor>250</valor>
                    <data>
                        <tax name="iva" value="50.30"></tax>
                    </data>
                </item>
                <item>
                    <nombre>Skateboard</nombre>
                    <valor>120</valor>
                    <data>
                        <tax name="iva" value="25.0"></tax>
                    </data>
                </item>
                <item>
                    <nombre>Motorcycle</nombre>
                    <valor>900</valor>
                    <data>
                        <tax name="iva" value="120.50"></tax>
                    </data>
                </item>
            </items>
        </tienda>]]>
    </detalle>
</data>
```

I am working with
`import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET` 
for example

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = ET.fromstring(stringBase64)
ite = xml.find('.//detalle').text
tixml = ET.fromstring(ite)
```

Comment: Base64 is Base64 and not an XML string. You can't parse the base64 string as XML directly. You need to undo the base64 operation and pass that to ET

Comment: yes, i do it in the code,

stringBase64= base64.b64decode(codeBase64).decode("utf-8", "ignore")

Comment: thanks for the observation, I need get a iterable list from this XML, for example like it:
    Item 1: Bicycle, value $250
    Item 2: Skateboard, value $120

Comment: base64 = base64decode(...) is bad naming. The result is not base64, so why have it in the name then?

Comment: That XML is invalid. `<info>Listado de items</prueba>` tags don't match. Also: `</comprobante>` has no opening tag

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use BeautifulSoup4 (BS4) to do this.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#Read XML file
with open("example.xml", "r") as f:
    contents = f.readlines()

#Create Soup object
soup = BeautifulSoup(contents, 'xml')

#find all the item tags
item_tags = soup.find_all("item") #returns everything in the <item> tags

#find the nombre and valor tags within each item
results = {}
for item in item_tags:
    num = item.find("nombre").text
    val = item.find("valor").text
    results[str(num)] = val

#Prints dictionary with key value pairs from the xml
print(results)
```

Comment: Thanks!!! and if you had another tag and needed to get a value, for example:

<item>
<nombre>Skateboard</nombre>
<valor>120</valor>
<data>
<tax name="iva" value="50.30"></tax>
</data>
</item>

Comment: to show some like it:
Item 1: Bicycle, value $250, iva_tax: 50.30

Comment: You can simply do the same as above:
item.find("data").item.find("tax").value